# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while using scale

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-9a56f92ca2dd> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
----> 2 X_transform = scale(X_transform)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in scale(X, axis, with_mean, with_std, copy)
    143     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', copy=copy, ensure_2d=False,
    144                     warn_on_dtype=True, estimator='the scale function',
--> 145                     dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES, force_all_finite='allow-nan')
    146     if sparse.issparse(X):
    147         if with_mean:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    525             try:
    526                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 527                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    528             except ComplexWarning:
    529                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is my code `X_transform` is an array of size `16000*300`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
X_transform = scale(X_transform)
```

Where am I going wrong? It contains values of float type.

This is my X_transform
[image]

Comment: What is `X_transform`? type and inner types?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I edited the question

Comment: you should include data as code (that can be copy-pasted and played with), not photos. But from the photo, your problem is that you should have a 2-dimensional array, not an array of arrays. Check about numpy arrays creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X_transform` is not a numpy array of floats. Convert it to an array properly (2D array, not a 1D array of 1D arrays) and then it will work as expected.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it..or should I loop it twice and do it?

Comment: No, you cannot loop, it won't work. You have to convert you data properly to a 2D array. But this code is not int he question, so we cannot tell you what to change :/